# Finding maximum values from each subarrays of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array:

```py
x = array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [24, 25, 26],
        [30, 31, 32]],

       [[21, 22, 23],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [33, 34, 35]]])
```

I want to find the max values of each subarrays and store them in lets say an array. So the output should be:

```py
output = array([14,17,32,35])
```

Now, one can easily do this using a loop, however, I want to avoid it. `np.max(x)` is giving output 35, that is the max value of the entire array. `np.max(axis)` also is not working (I am not very sure it would work, but I tried anyway)
Anyone, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```py
[max(j) for j in [max(i) for i in x.tolist()]]
```

Output:

> [14, 17, 32, 35]

Comment: but my required output, as I mentioned in the question is: [14,17,32,35]

Comment: I edited my response to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.max` for `axis=1` twice

```py
x.max(axis=1).max(axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
Out[203]: array([14, 17, 32, 35])
```